# cakephp 3 : How to add class in form button?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have tried this line to add class in cakephp form button, but class is not showing in html

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login',['class'=>'login-btn'])); ?>
```

How can I add class in button ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your example doesn't work, because the `__()` Call shouldn't include the array for the options of the button. Please try the following:

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login'),['class'=>'login-btn']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on this below:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->button('Login',['class'=>'login-btn']); ?>
```

A good reference here: [Creating input elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-input-elements)

**Update**

`__()` is for [internalization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions). Using this will look in to your localization file and output it's corresponding translation. In your case, you include the options inside `__()` which I think it will cause an error but if it didn't, it will look for it's translated version and also this means `['class'=>'login-btn']` is not considered as an option anymore.

Comment: This is working fine ! If you don't mind can you explain me why 
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login',['class'=>'login-btn'])); ?> 
line not working? both like showing same to me.

Comment: @AlimonKarim I have added an answer to your question on my post.

Answer (score 0):

it has to be inside an array : try this

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login'),array('class'=>'login-btn')); ?>
```